# tables, formating

Tags: tables, siunitx

struggling with this table, any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} \begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l 
               S[table-format=-1.2(2)] 
                S[table-format=table-format=1.1e1] } 
\toprule 
  {\textbf{Approach}} & $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ & $\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$ \\
   \midrule
1   &  -0.61(17)        & Inf. \\
2   &  -0.60(17)        & Inf. \\
3   &  -0.59(18)        & 3$\times$10$^6$\\ 
4   &  -0.56(20)        & Inf. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption[]
 \label{}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
```

Comment: (i) Please be more specific about what's troubling you about your table. We can't read minds. (ii) Please complete your code to make it compilable.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem other than you adding math mode into the last column when the S column also sets the column in math mode. Try writing the entry as just 3e6. The three inf. entries my confuse the S column, perhaps `{Inf.}` is better (then it will be centered)

Comment: I tried daleif suggestion and I got this error..........! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\@@par ...\hangindent \caption@hangindent }{{1.1}{i}}

Comment: You should also check your `\caption`. The argument is missing.

Comment: I fixed the \caption but it is still giving me that error?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use boldface in the header: `\bm{\beta}` and `\beta` are two different math entities.

Also the first column need not be boldface. The third column, having just one number, can just be `c`, with `\num` for the number; if this is only an unabridged version, you should brace the non numeric entries.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  >{\bfseries}l 
  S[table-format=-1.2(2)] 
  c
}
\toprule 
Approach & {$\bm{\beta}$} & $\bm{\chi^{2}}$ \\
\midrule
1   &  -0.61(17)        & Inf. \\
2   &  -0.60(17)        & Inf. \\
3   &  -0.59(18)        & \num{3e6} \\ 
4   &  -0.56(20)        & Inf. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{A caption}
\label{label}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  l 
  S[table-format=-1.2(2)] 
  c
}
\toprule 
Approach & {$\beta$} & $\chi^{2}$ \\
\midrule
1   &  -0.61(17)        & Inf. \\
2   &  -0.60(17)        & Inf. \\
3   &  -0.59(18)        & \num{3e6} \\ 
4   &  -0.56(20)        & Inf. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{A caption}
\label{label2}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  l 
  S[table-format=-1.2(2)] 
  S[table-format=1.0e1]
}
\toprule 
Approach & {$\beta$} & $\chi^{2}$ \\
\midrule
1   &  -0.61(17)        & {Inf.} \\
2   &  -0.60(17)        & {Inf.} \\
3   &  -0.59(18)        & 3e6 \\ 
4   &  -0.56(20)        & {Inf.} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{A caption}
\label{label3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should be your table and be compilable:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c % I think centred column looks better here
               S[table-format=-1.2(2)] 
                S[table-format=1.1e1] } 
\toprule 
  Approach & $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ & $\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$ \\
   \midrule
1   &  -0.61(17)        & {Inf.} \\
2   &  -0.60(17)        & {Inf.} \\
3   &  -0.59(18)        & 3e6 \\ 
3   &  -0.59(18)        & 3.0e6 \\ % for comparison
4   &  -0.56(20)        & {Inf.} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{test}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Is there anything not as you want it?

Comment: Row 3 : why is 3    X    10^6 so separated?

Comment: @yoyo Because `1.1e1` expects a floating number like `3.5` so it leaves space for the `.`.

Comment: @yoyo because you specified the number to have a decimal. Insert `3.0e6` and the separation is gone.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do myself with no sucess.  Many thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\caption[]{My nice table}
    \label{tab:mytable}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l
                S[table-format=-1.2(2)]
                S[table-format= 1.0e1] }
    \toprule
Approach    & {$\boldsymbol{\beta}$}    & {$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$}  \\
   \midrule
1           &  -0.61(17)                & {Inf.}                    \\
2           &  -0.60(17)                & {Inf.}                    \\
3           &  -0.59(18)                & 3e6                       \\
4           &  -0.56(20)                & {Inf.}                    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

or

    \begin{table}[htbp]
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
    \centering
\caption[]{My nice table again}
    \label{tab:mytable}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c
                S[table-format=-1.2(2)]
                S[table-format= 1.0e1] }
    \toprule
Approach    & {$\boldsymbol{\beta}$}    & {$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$}  \\
   \midrule
1           &  -0.61(17)                & {Inf.}                    \\
2           &  -0.60(17)                & {Inf.}                    \\
3           &  -0.59(18)                & 3e6                       \\
4           &  -0.56(20)                & {Inf.}                    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```